# How to run Flask app on same server as a PHP/Apache website?

Tags: apache, flask, gunicorn

Couldn't find a question that had this specific setup, so was having trouble making some of the other answers work in my situation.

I have a CentOS server running a PHP-based website with Apache as the web server (working fine). I'm trying to now deploy a Flask-based app (using Gunicorn proxied through Apache) on a different port.

In my main httpd.conf file I have:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
# Include the proxy information for VMS Flask Application
Include conf/extra/httpd-foo.conf
</IfModule>
```

And in my httpd-foo.conf file I have:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8000/
Timeout 2400
ProxyTimeout 240
```

PHP website runs at: https://myphpwebsite.com
I'd like the Flask app to run at: https://myphpwebsite.com/foo

The problem I'm encountering is when I visit the Flask URL, is I encounter 2 issues. First, if I don't include a trailing slash after "foo", I get a 404 (because that directory doesn't actually exist in the real web directory. The second issue is that all my Flask routes assume "/" is "root", which it is not now. I don't know how to tell Flask that all routes should have "/foo" pre-pended to them.

Is this possible?

-- Some additional info --

I've tried running the gunicorn command with the "-E" option to tell it the SCRIPT_NAME which seemed to help only for the main page:

```
gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -t 180 -e SCRIPT_NAME=/foo -w 4
```

Currently, if I visit https://myphpwebsite.com/foo/ it results in a 500 Internal Server Error. I can see that my "not logged in" redirect appears to work and takes me to https://myphpwebsite.com/foo/login properly, but again it's just resulting in a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of the same setup (apache, php, gunicorn, flask), and what works for me is to use `VirtualHost` and embed the `ProxyPass` in a `Location`-directive. So my conf-file looks something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Location "/foo">
          ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, calls to https://mydomein.com/ are managed by Apache (managing php als always), and all the requests done to https://mydomein.com/foo are being delegated to GUnicorn (listening on port 8000).

Comment: What happens to the /foo part of the path, is that sent to GUnicorn? In my case I see requests being proxied but the Flask server always answers 404, so I suspect I have botched the config for rewriting the path correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late respons. Yes, in this config the requests to `/foo` are being proxied to GUnicorn. Since you state that Flask is returning a 404, it seems that your problem is indeed somewhere further up the pipeline...